# Row replacement in array in C

Tags: c, arrays

```
A[10][10]
B[10][10]
```

In [c](/questions/tagged/c) can we use

```
A[5]=B[4];
```

is this legal or we have to replace each element one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your definitions of `A` and `B`, the assignment `A[5] = B[4];` is illegal.

You can easily replace each element one by one

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) A[5][i] = B[4][i];
```

or, assuming the arrays are of the same base type, use `memmove()` (or `memcpy()` because arrays do not overlap)

```
#include <string.h>
memmove(A[5], B[4], 10 * sizeof B[4][0]);
// memcpy(A[5], B[4], 10 * sizeof B[4][0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are not assignable so you cannot do that.

You have 2 alternatives:

1. Loop through the array and assign each element individually.   Or
2. You can use `memcpy` or `memmove`. This is possible because arrays are guaranteed to be contiguous in memory so

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign array types in C. So you either have to copy element-wise, or use `memcpy`.

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't have real multidimensional arrays like in some other languages.

C have array of arrays.

In this declaration

`int a[8][12];`

`a` is an array 8 of array 12 of `int`.

So `a[0][0]` is of type `int` and `a[5]` is of type array 12 of `int`.

`a[5]` being an array, it cannot be used as the left operand of the assignment operator. C treats arrays as second class citizens and array cannot be assigned.

C says (quoted from C99 standard):

*(6.5.16p2) "An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as
 its left operand"*

and

*(6.3.2.1p1) "A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that does not have array type, [...]"*

To copy array objects, one solution is to use the `memcpy` function.

Comment: (I'm not the downvoter) Maybe they took exception to the statement that "C doesn't have real multidimensional arrays". In examples such as this, where the dimensions are known at compile time, I think the multi-dimensional array works quite well in C. For example, ith `int a[8][12];` there is no indirect pointer-lookup required. [ Also, you're not the only one to get a downvote with an answer that wasn't incorrect :-) ]

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Thank your for the comment. This was also my guess. And actually I put the word *real* before *multidimensional array* in the answer to prevent those who would downvote because of this statement ;)

Answer (score -1):

You're not allowed to directly copy arrays in C like that, but there is a workaround. You could wrap the array inside a `struct`

```
struct int_array_10 {
    int x[10];
};

struct int_array_10 A[10];
struct int_array_10 B[10];

int main() {
        A[5] = B[4]; // this works
}
```

This compiles and is correct. It can be a little inconvenient though, as you know have to access elements with something like `A[3].x[4]` instead of `A[3][4]`. Maybe you would define an accessor macro instead, allowing to read and write elements more conveniently:

```
#define get(a,X,Y) (a[X].x[Y])
```

which you might use this like:

```
get(A,3,4) = get(B,7,8);
```

Comment: this is a terrible solution, this leads to bad coding practices, It's hard to maintain for other coders. There's a reason why loops were introduced to programming languages

Comment: Strong words, @Mellowcandle. I haven't learned anything from your comment.

Comment: In this case a loop is a terrible solution. It's much better to use memcpy. The compiler can optimize that properly, and it's easier to read. (Yes, the compiler can also optimize a simple loop - mostly, but it's too easy to do in a way the compiler can't trust to be sure.)

Comment: OK, I'll try to make myself clearer... It seems that sometime one tries to force functionality that doean't exist in C in peculiar ways. I'm working a lot with legacy C code. and I can tell you from experience that seeing something like "A[3].X[4]" is going to cause a programmer to scratch his head and say what the f...

Comment: I should also say that the wrap-it-in-a-struct solution is effectively a memcpy underneath. @Mellowcandle says it's bad practice, but I'd disagree (although it depends on the case) - in fact, doing it this ways means that you can add new data into the array in future (should you need to) without having to rewrite any exiting code.

Comment: Maybe the outer array should also be inside a struct. Which would lead to the more readable `A.row[3].column[4]`.

Comment: I agree that memcpy is a better approach than looping.